# Retrieving Timestamp paramerter from MYSQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a java MVC architecture (Simple MVC not used any Framework) which will connect to the database. A query will fetch the time-stamp value which is in the MySQL DB. But I am not getting the expected output it is throwing an exception.

Expected output: **2015-05-12 11:29:21**

Present output: Value **'0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp**

For this exception, I googled and found answers that said to add parameters in the DB URL. So I tried that:

"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/acc_dev_db?**connectTimeout=100000&autoReconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull**"

After adding this I am getting null as output.

Here is my code :

```
public HeartBeatBean getHBDetails(Double nidev) throws SQLException
{  
 HeartBeatBean hbBean = null;  
 if(nidev > 0)
 {  
     pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT nidevid,hbtimestamp  FROM nidhb where nidevid=? ORDER  BY nidhbid");


   try {  
        pstmt.setDouble(1, nidev);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); 
        if(rs.next())
        {  
            hbBean = new HeartBeatBean();  
            rs.getTimestamp("hbtimestamp");
            System.out.println(rs.getTimestamp("hbtimestamp"));
            hbBean.setHbtimestamp(rs.getTimestamp("hbtimestamp"));


        }  

    } 
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {  
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());  
        }
```

Any ideas why I'm not able to fetch my timestamp?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Tom Jinckheere :How to retrieve time-stamp values from DB

Comment: In my DB i have timestamp values but if I fetch,I am  getting null

Comment: Yes, but when you retrieve 0000-00-00 00:00:00 it is converted to null. Thats why you added the parameters to the URL. Did you allready try it with another (valid) date?

Comment: My actual value in DB is: 2015-05-12 11:29:21,If i fetch without adding the parameters ,I am getting this -   Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: please read my above  question which i have described

Comment: ok, do you get the expected result when just executing the query? And update your question, stating the expected result.

Comment: Please check it is EDITED

Comment: If I execute query in MySQL ,I am getting expected o/p

Comment: in the bean class what is the class type for `'hbtimestamp'` variable?

Comment: Sir it is Timestamp -public Timestamp getHbtimestamp() {
  return hbtimestamp;
 }

Comment: Can Any one help me!!